# BLE pairing by NFC on Android

Tags: android, nfc, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm trying to use NFC in order to pair two Android BLE devices. I followed latest specifications released from NFC Forum & BT SIG, called [Bluetooth Secure Simple Pairing Using
NFC](http://members.nfc-forum.org/apps/group_public/download.php/18688/NFCForum-AD-BTSSP_1_1.pdf) and I'm interested in static handover. This means I'd to write an NDEF message on an NFC tag (formatted according to specifications above) with one device, then the other one reads this tag and keep information to start BLE pairing. I'm using Android 4.4.2. and this approach works fine with Bluetooth, with no need to have specific app to manage handover, Android does the work!

But with BLE this approach doesn't work. I think the problem is related to MIME-type that I'd to write in NDEF message. For Bluetooth is `application/vnd.bluetooth.ep.oob` while for BLE is `application/vnd.bluetooth.le.oob`. When I tap device/tag, Android detects that there's a new tag with BLE MIME-type but doesn't perform any action,  just shows me the screen "New tag collected", like it was unknown MIME-type. I noticed that NFC Forum specifications was released on 2014-01-09 and in [Compatibility document for Android 4.4](https://static.googleusercontent.com/media/source.android.com/it//compatibility/android-cdd.pdf) there aren't references about BLE handover, just Bluetooth.

Does someone know if BLE pairing by NFC is supported and works on Android 4.4? And on Android 5?

Answer (score 2):

I managed to test NFC/BLE handover on a Nexus 6 running Android 5 and the MIME-type     `application/vnd.bluetooth.le.oob` has been recognised! Therefore the limit is in the Android version ...

Comment: @shreyashirday I simply created an NdefRecord by [createMime\(mimeType, mimeData\)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/NdefRecord.html) function, passing the string `application/vnd.bluetooth.le.oob` as mimeType. The mimeData (payload) depends on some options and you can find more details in the aforementioned document [\(Bluetooth Secure Simple Pairing Using NFC\)](http://members.nfc-forum.org/apps/group_public/download.php/18688/NFCForum-AD-BTSSP_1_1.pdf). At page 32 there is also an example (payolad content starts from LE address field).

Comment: @shreyashirday However the only mandatory payload fields are the BLE MAC address and the BLE role of the node ... Then you can pass the NdeRecord to [NdefMessage](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/NdefMessage.html) constructor, getting an NdefMessage writable on a tag. In this way, by tapping a so formatted tag with an Android 5+ device, the NDEF message is automatically recognised as a BLE handover request.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read characteristic, you need to use read method of that property. Sample given with the SDK 4.3 works good. Also connectivity problem exists in all other devices except Samsung.